# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed in django admin panel when creating/editing/deleting a user. (Using custom user model.)

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

So I'm using a custom user model

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name, address, number, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not address:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not number:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email.lower()),
            full_name=full_name,
            address = address,
            number=number,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email, full_name, address, number, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a staff user with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name,
            address,
            numbe,
            password = password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name, address, number, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name,
            address,
            number,
            password = password,
        )
        user.staff = True
        user.admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank = False, null = False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank = False, null = False)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank = False, null = False)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a admin user; non super-user
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser
    # notice the absence of a "Password field", that's built in.

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name', 'address', 'number'] # Email & Password are required by default.

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        "Is the user active?"
        return self.active
```

This is my admin.py for the app

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

from .forms import UserAdminChangeForm, UserAdminCreationForm
from .models import User

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    form = UserAdminChangeForm
    add_form = UserAdminCreationForm

    # The fields to be used in displaying the User model.
    # These override the definitions on the base UserAdmin
    # that reference specific fields on auth.User.
    list_display = ('email', 'admin')
    list_filter = ('admin',)
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('full_name', 'address', 'number')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin', 'active', 'staff')}),
    )
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'full_name', 'address', 'number', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

And finally forms.py

```
    from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

from .models import User

class UserAdminCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'full_name', 'address', 'number')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserAdminCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class UserAdminChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for updating users. Includes all the fields on
    the user, but replaces the password field with admin's
    password hash display field.
    """
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'full_name', 'address', 'number', 'password', 'active', 'admin')

    def clean_password(self):
        # Regardless of what the user provides, return the initial value.
        # This is done here, rather than on the field, because the
        # field does not have access to the initial value
        return self.initial["password"]
```

So it works great when i create a superuser through the console with manage.py but when i decide to edit, delete or create another user in the gui admin panel i get a "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed". Which i don't understand, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked around and the code should work in older versions of django. Sadly it won't work in django 2.0 or above. If anyone wants an alternative I found [this](https://www.fomfus.com/articles/how-to-use-email-as-username-for-django-authentication-removing-the-username) to be perfect for my project, explanation is simple as well.

Answer (score 6):

I think i have found a solution for this. The problem could well be caused by the circular dependencies issues when you migrate your default AUTH_USER_MODEL to a custom model in the middle of the project.

From Django Documentation

> Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL after you’ve created database tables is significantly more difficult since it affects foreign keys and many-to-many relationships, for example.
>
> This change can’t be done automatically and requires manually fixing your schema, moving your data from the old user table, and possibly manually reapplying some migrations. See #25313 for an outline of the steps.
>
> Due to limitations of Django’s dynamic dependency feature for swappable models, the model referenced by AUTH_USER_MODEL must be created in the first migration of its app (usually called 0001_initial); otherwise, you’ll have dependency issues.
>
> In addition, you may run into a CircularDependencyError when running your migrations as Django won’t be able to automatically break the dependency loop due to the dynamic dependency. If you see this error, you should break the loop by moving the models depended on by your user model into a second migration. (You can try making two normal models that have a ForeignKey to each other and seeing how makemigrations resolves that circular dependency if you want to see how it’s usually done.)

**The best way to tackle this is to drop the table and remove all migration files and then re run the migrations with your newly made custom model. Hope this will work.**

More details on how to migrate from a built in model to a new model can be found here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: It will delete your whole database.** If you have some important data then backup it by dumpdata and then restore it by loaddata. [for more info check here (I am not sure about this).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rrsn2WEG5M&t=57s)

It is very difficult to change AUTH_USER_MODEL in the middle of the project. [See the note in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project).
Infect after you are done with your first migration of Django tables, you will face problems.

**Idea is**: You need to include your **custom user model** with its entry in setting.py (AUTH_USER_MODEL = [custom user model] ) in your first-ever migration (where django create its own table like auth_group, dajango_migrations etc... ) of Django project.

**Warning**: If you have started server then Django itself create database and then this will not work, so please do not start the server.

- Delete dbsqlite3 database file, delete all your migrations files and its binary files (In app/migration/**pycache** ) except init file and comment out all your models and it's dependencies (like, you have used model in any form then comment it also).
- Now uncomment only custom user model
- add AUTH_USER_MODEL in setting.py (AUTH_USER_MODEL = [custom user model] )
- and then run makemigrations and migrate. (this will create your all Django tables and your custom user model.)

It is done.

now you can start the server.

after that uncomment all other models and migrate them.

Answer (score 0):

For django 2.2+:

1. If it's test data -> then you have to delete all the migrations and pycache 
   folders from all apps and project and delete 'db.sqlite3' file also.
2. Make migrations and migrate apps then it works. 
   (i have same issues and it worked using this method.)
3. If data is import you can backup data easily using fixtures google it.