# Django - FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when changing custom user model in admin page

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've created a custom User model, User manager, and User admin in Django 2.0.  **Everything works correctly except when I try to change a User's attributes as a superuser in the admin page.**  When I try to change anything, I get

```
IntegrityError at /admin/home/myuser/14/change/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/home/myuser/14/change/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, as I wasn't even aware that my models had any foreign keys in the first place.  I've tried all that I can think of.

models.py:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, name, organization, password, **extra_fields):
        if not all([email, name, organization, password]):
            raise ValueError("All fields are required")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name, organization=organization, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, name, organization, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", False)
        return self._create_user(email=email, name=name, organization=organization, password=password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, organization, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        #extra_fields.setdefault("is_admin", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, name, organization, password, **extra_fields)


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    can_use_monsoon = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'organization']
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
```

admin.py:

```
class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model=MyUser
        fields = ('email', 'name', 'organization', 'can_use_monsoon')


@admin.register(MyUser)
class MyUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = MyUser
    add_form_template = 'admin/auth/user/add_form.html'
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('name', 'organization')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('can_use_monsoon',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    list_display = ('email', 'name', 'organization')
    list_filter = ('can_use_monsoon', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups')
    search_fields = ('email', 'name', 'organization')
    ordering = ('email', 'name', 'organization')
    filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```

I've changed the AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py to point at the appropriate model.  I've also made all migrations.  I've even tried flushing the database and deleting the migration files, but no luck.  There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054375/foreign-key-constraint-failed-in-django-admin-panel-when-creating-editing-deleti), but I've tried the solutions and they aren't helping.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the entire traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/home/myuser/18/change/

Django Version: 2.0
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['home',
 'config',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

The above exception (FOREIGN KEY constraint failed) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  574.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
  1556.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1450.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py" in __exit__
  212.                         connection.commit()

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in commit
  261.         self._commit()

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\joshu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py" in _commit
  239.                 return self.connection.commit()

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /admin/home/myuser/18/change/
Exception Value: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

And the Request Information:

```
Request information
USER
test@test.com

GET
No GET data

POST
Variable    Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'VO8VhCt8ICJTYmgK6e0EB2ZupXomfdPzCsqtXkYgKbR5ikVIAk0DT38bamaU79Qx'
email   
'test@test.com'
name    
'TestName'
organization    
'TestOrg2'
_save   
'Save'
```

Comment: What attribute are you changing? Are you selecting a value from a drop down or free typing something in?

Comment: @dfundako The error occurs when I try to change any attribute.  I've tried changing just text values (e.g. freely typing something in) as well as just a Boolean value (checking a checkbox that was previously unchecked).

Comment: Do you have debug mode on in your settings file? That would dump more data probably.

Comment: @dfundako Yes I do.  Which part of the error would you like to see? The entire traceback?  Or the request information?  The settings?

Comment: Dump the entire I guess.

Comment: @dfundako Added the full error to the original post.