# Foreign key constraint failed when changing data form admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

i was trying to insert some test data through the admin panel but I keep getting stuck on the `FOREIGN KEY constraint failed` error.
I'm trying to create an `Event` this is how my class looks:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Create your models here.
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    end_time = models.DateTimeField()
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, max_length=254)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    
    def get_events_from_weekday(weekday):
        index_week = weekday.weekday()
        week_start = weekday - timedelta(days=index_week)
        week_end = week_start + timedelta(days=6)

        return Event.objects.filter(start_time__range=[week_start, week_end])
    
    def get_event_from_start_time(start_time):
        return Event.objects.filter(start_time=start_time)
```

Also for my customer class i cannot create an object through the admin panel. But I can create a customer through my register page. This is my customer model

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, UserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.    
class CustomerManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self,name, last_name, email, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Customers must have an email address')
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            name=name,
            last_name=last_name,
            phone=phone,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    
    def create_user(self,name, last_name, email, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        return self._create_user(name, last_name, email, phone, password, **extra_fields)
    
    def create_superuser(self, name, last_name, email, phone, password, **extra_fields):
        print('create superuser')
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        
        return self._create_user(name, last_name, email, phone, password, **extra_fields)

class Customers (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    objects = CustomerManager()
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'last_name', 'phone']
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Customer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Customers'
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str({
            'name': self.name,
            'last_name': self.last_name,
            'email': self.email,
            'phone': self.phone,
            'date_joined': self.date_joined,
        })
        
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.last_name
    
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_user_from_email(email):
        return Customers.objects.get(email=email)
```

This is my customer `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from customers.forms import CustomerForm, LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(ValueError)
            return render(request, 'customers/register_success.html')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            return render(request, 'customers/register.html', {'form': form, 'error': 'Invalid form'})
    context = {}
    form = CustomerForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'customers/register.html', context)
```

Also I registered customer as my `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'customers.Customers'`  in my `settings.py`.

I'm not sure what can cause this error, I have removed my database multiple times already, also removed my migrations but I still get this error.
I look forward to everyone's thoughts on this!

Comment: Found a fix in the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054375/foreign-key-constraint-failed-in-django-admin-panel-when-creating-editing-deleti#:~:text=If%20you%20see%20this%20error,see%20how%20it's%20usually%20done.)